# Admin hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

Can any user in Wordpress with full admin privileges (ALL capabilities turned on) be hidden from other users with admin privileges (with comparatively lesser capabilities turned on) in the ‘Users’ area (list_users)?

I want to create a sort of hierarchy of administrator roles and users, where the user with the top admin role with ALL capabilities should be hidden from other users with lesser admin roles and capabilities – in the ‘Users’ area.

How can I achieve / implement this?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

To entirely hide the user will be very hard and would require a lot of hooking and filtering, even if the super admin is only passively active (no post editing, publishing, etc.)

If you just want to hide the user from the backend users list the pre_user_query hook will probably be helpful:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_query/

Alternative solution: Do not make the other users admins. Create a custom role with custom capabilities. An admin is intended to do/see everything on a wordpress site except for a multisite installation, where the network admin is even stronger.

Comment: `add_action('pre_user_query','yoursite_pre_user_query');
function yoursite_pre_user_query($user_search) {
  global $current_user;
  $username = $current_user->user_login;

  if ($username == 'DESIRED USERNAME GOES HERE') { 

  }

  else {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1',
      "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.user_login != 'DESIRED USERNAME GOES HERE'",$user_search->query_where);
  }
}

function hide_user_count(){
?>
<style>
.wp-admin.users-php span.count {display: none;}
</style>
<?php
}

add_action('admin_head','hide_user_count');` [source: forgotten!]

Comment: Yes, the code above seems to work for users list. But I can't figure out how to hide specific author names from the author columns in various backend navigation sub-menu work areas (sub-panels). Although I can hide entire author columns from submenu work areas, but can't limit the hiding to one or several *specific* submenu. It gets hidden in many other unintended submenus too - which is very unhelpful. So, can you suggest any idea how to either hide (i) (preferred) specific author names from the author columns, or, (ii) hide entire author columns from specified submenu work areas?

Answer (score 0):

The code below seems to work for users list **ONLY**:

```
add_action('pre_user_query','yoursite_pre_user_query');
function yoursite_pre_user_query($user_search) {
  global $current_user;
  $username = $current_user->user_login;

  if ($username == 'DESIRED USERNAME GOES HERE') { 

  }

  else {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1',
      "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.user_login != 'DESIRED USERNAME GOES HERE'",$user_search->query_where);
  }
}

function hide_user_count(){
?>
<style>
.wp-admin.users-php span.count {display: none;}
</style>
<?php
}

add_action('admin_head','hide_user_count');
```

[Disclaimer: Code not mine, source forgotten.]